# Unable to sign into WSO2 identity server with certain AD users

Tags: wso2-identity-server

Seems to be that any new users added to AD are unable to sign into WSO2 unless the accounts were copied from a prior user account that was already setup before WSO2 was installed. I've tried looking at account attributes in AD, but can't seem to find anything different between them. Also seems that if user only had domain user access they are unable to sign in as well regardless if they were an old or new account.

When a new account tries to sign in it just says "Login Failed. Please check the username and password". I have verified that the login and password are correct for the users that are unable to sign in.

Comment: My apologies. What I posted above isn't exactly right from what I can see now. It is using the Name attribute to login instead of sAMAccountName. I've tried editing the user-mgt.xml file under the IS_HOME/repository/conf folder and replacing the cn value with sAMAccountName and restarting tomcat and WSO2, but it still only is using the Name attribute and not the sAMAccountName.